# Infer type from array literal

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an array, and returns an object whose keys are set using the values in the array.

Simplified example:

```
// arr will be an array of arrays of type [string] *or* [string, string]
function foo(arr) {
  const output = {}

  arr.forEach(value => {
    // if this value has length 2, use the second string as the key
    const key = value.length === 1 ? value[0] : value[1]

    // always use the first string as the value
    const value = value[0]

    output[key] = value
  })

  return output
}
```

For instance running `foo([['a', 'orange'], ['b'], ['c', 'apple'])` will produce `{ orange: 'a', b: 'b', apple: 'c' }` with type `{ orange: string, b: string, apple: string }` - let's call that type `R` - note that I don't really care about the values of `R` being literals. This would be a nice bonus, but the more general `string` type is adequate.

With Typescript I want to infer the return type of `foo`, `R`, from a generic for the input `arr`, `T`.

I can type `T` like so

```
function foo<T extends Array<[string, string?]>(arr: T) { ... }
```

**Is it then possible to infer `R` from `T`?**

---

Update

One potential issue I can see with this running against the limits of Typescript's power is that `R` will need to care about the order of values of `T` as you can of course specify duplicate keys.

I.e. it's not as pure as the similar generic object type -> generic object type mapping syntax `[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Thing ? ... : ...`.

If it's an issue, but there is any potential to hack around it and simply ignore it, i.e. only making this typesafe where there aren't any duplicate keys, that's fine for my usecase.

Comment: Unless you declare the array `const` you can't. In general the Typescript compiler cannot infer types from the elements of an array (because the exact elements will be known only at runtime).

Comment: declaring the array as `const` in the calling code is fine for my usecase! What would the syntax then be in the return type declaration of `foo`?

Comment: Nope, that would not work because the function argument is not `const`, you can call that function with *any* array.

Comment: Ah, so because of that limitation, doing this with generics is impossible?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVVRW) work for you?

Comment: @fog TS is able to infer the each element in tuple. Yo just need to declare generic parameter for each of them and put the appropriate constraints

Comment: @aleksxor this is great, thanks! I've given the check to @captain-yossarian for managing to do it without `const` but if you add this as an answer I will upvote :-)

Comment: @captain-yossarian true, and your answer is awesome. Looking at OP code made me think of the argument as a dynamic array (built in code), not a literal one: I am pretty sure that will not work.

Comment: @fog yes, TypeScript sometimes is tricky. Can't count how many times I was saying that smth is impossible in TS and how many times I was wrong :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is doable:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type Tuple<K, V = 1> = [K, V?]

type Elem = Tuple<any, any>

/**
 * Infers all elements in tuple and converts it
 * to object
 */
type Predicate<T> =
    T extends Tuple<infer K, infer V>
    ? V extends PropertyKey
    ? Record<V, K>
    : K extends PropertyKey
    ? Record<K, K>
    : never
    : never

/**
 * Iterate through argument
 */
type Reducer<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Tuple<any, any>>,
    Result extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > = Arr extends []
    // last step of iteration
    ? Result
    // if there are still tuples in the array
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Tuple<any, any>>
    ? H extends Elem
    // call utility type recursively and produce record type with help of predicate
    ? Reducer<Tail, Result & Predicate<H>>
    : never
    : never
    : never

// we need to infer each key and property, thats why I used extra K,V generics
declare function foo<K extends string, V extends string, Tuples extends Tuple<K, V>[]>(tuples: [...Tuples]): Reducer<[...Tuples]>

foo([['a', 'orange'], ['b'], ['c', 'apple']]) // Record<"orange", "a"> & Record<"b", "b"> & Record<"apple", "c">
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBANQIYBsCuMDOAeAKgPjgF45cBtAaxggHsAzUgXQG5RRJZS0oUZsBpADSJicAIyESZIYgD8jNuGjwAorwC2o3N17YkAOwjCDEfIo7wACgCcYAEwCWAYyRg%20BYqDjfScGAA83fTtMLh4%20B306GGs4GUjo2IQzEB84WREAoJC4GxpYa0h%20ai8fDIAlGCcaaztsBGF%20FLSALji-QJhg0LyCopLUsrhK6tqBRuafNv0YADcY0u9puYWQdmVh%20zQnGOxFuABBa1isrpzKpDsafRQII%20skCDwdPhNjQ3x8QX3KzDQUMAdbKhEY1OqYMDWSIAc3eplEAG8AL77SSHY5As6hMgKQbeCpYf5gfZte6Y7pwMgJGJwAASuLSGVp5Jyahg6n2BL%20ALgADJcrZHC43NhaZMlnAZvNrCT0SdOhTbJdrrdKdTYrThAA6HXq0hIBwoBlDXAGlAskEwZU3O7HR7PcJ6Qxwz6cukWuBsjl49KbOzbXamw3CX5EvkC%20zOVx8MXiuDLaWyqWrVqSlYytYgOxVFBIWxwOhofROMAOa4Fmg0AQeiFQ-SwzIKnK1mHCbThUKnCnt3QyZI4-AACjAL0wbTIOq1PawjAAlG1Kv6dtZsBOddPMIwUqA6JXB2QyAByJCH4SHmoGaEwQ%20MYRHgBGN7vh6cp7gx6g4Rvc7gAHpf5sox1AARBe9YwMBwjAUgwGEPyoJjMB96QXASGweGCEgUgn68ChwFOLBoBAA)

No need to use `const` assertion in this case

More examples you can find [in my blog](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce)

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) you can find how to infer other data structures from function arguments

Comment: This is incredible! Really impressive workaround for `const` and TIL about `infer`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Version working when declaring function argument `as const`:

```ts
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Result<T extends readonly [string] | readonly [unknown, string]> = UnionToIntersection<
    T extends readonly [infer V] ? { [k in Extract<V, string>]: V } :
    T extends readonly [infer V, infer K] ? { [k in Extract<K, string>]: V } : never
>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXkkVW)